# Лёгкая графическая библиотека для создания 1-bit изображений в C

Tags: linux, c, изображения, bitmap, graphics

Существует ли (Или есть ли какие-нибудь уроки по созданию) лёгкая графическая библиотека для создания **1-bit** изображений в **C** ?

Нужно лишь две функции:

- Задавать размер изображения.
- Рисовать на изображении линии по координатам (*Только линии!*).

Comment: [Алгоритм Брезенхема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая библиотека - [libgd](https://github.com/libgd/libgd):

> GD is an open source code library for the dynamic creation of images
>   by programmers. GD is written in C, and "wrappers" are available for
>   Perl, PHP and other languages. GD creates PNG, JPEG, GIF, WebP, XPM,
>   BMP images, among other formats. GD is commonly used to generate
>   charts, graphics, thumbnails, and most anything else, on the fly.
>   While not restricted to use on the web, the most common applications
>   of GD involve website development.

Она лёгкая, но, как видно из описания, не совсем примитивная. Можно создавать как индесированные так и полноцветные изображения, рисовать различные примитивы (в том числе и линии) и рендерить текст. Есть встроенная поддержка BMP, GIF, TGA, WBMP (остальные форматы подключаются через внешние библиотеки).

Пример использования ([arc.c](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/master/examples/arc.c)):

```
#include "gd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    gdImagePtr im;
    FILE *fp;
    int cor_rad = 60;
    im = gdImageCreateTrueColor(400, 400);
    gdImageFilledRectangle(im, 0, 0, 399, 399, 0x00FFFFFF);

    gdImageFilledArc (im, cor_rad, 399 - cor_rad, cor_rad *2, cor_rad *2, 90, 180, 0x0, gdPie);

    fp = fopen("b.png", "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't save png image.\n");
        gdImageDestroy(im);
        return 1;
    }
#ifdef HAVE_LIBPNG
    gdImagePng(im, fp);
#else
    printf("No PNG support. Cannot save image.\n");
#endif
    fclose(fp);

    gdImageDestroy(im);
    return 0;
}
```